# Al pinchar en el boton login no inicia sesión

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Cuando intento loguearme con mi cuenta la web se refresca y no comprueba los datos de usuario que ingreso.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como corregir este bug?

La tabla de usuarios es esta:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_user` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(233) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `verif` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

El script de inicio de sesión es este:

```
<?php
 $conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","","web");

 if (isset($_GET['login'])) {
   $user = $_POST['username'];
   $pass = $_POST['password'];
   $sql = $conn->query("select password from user where usuario='$user'");

   if ($sql) {
     $data = $sql->fetch_assoc();

     if ($pass=$data['password']) {
       header("loation: /home.php");


     }else {echo "Password incorrect!";}
  }

 }
?>


            <form class="" action="" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="username" class="username" value="" placeholder="Username">
              <input type="password" name="password" class="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
              <input type="submit" name="login" class="button-redond" value="Login">
              <span><a class="resetp" href="#">¿Lost Password?</a></span>
            </form>
```

Comment: Ya probé añadiendo index.php y añadiendo el código que lo valida en otro y pasa lo mismo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

en el header tienes

```
header("loation: /home.php")
```

loation no existe, sera por eso que no puedes

intenta con

```
header("Location: /home.php")
```